# Delete rows that does not match elements in an array

Tags: python, pandas, rows

Good day!
I'm having some problems of updating my csv file (I'm using pandas). I want the code to delete a row in the csv file if the row element is the same as my defined array

For example if I have the following rows in my csv file:

```
and 2
hi  3
or  4
is  5
hello 6
```

and the defined array a is given by:

```
a = ['and', 'or', 'is']

d = {}

for k, v in reader.values:
    if a == k:
        break
    else:
        d[k] = int(v)
```

reader is the name of the variable I used to open the csv file using pandas

I'm expecting a dictionary where the word listed in the array would not be stored in d. I'm expecting this kind of output:

```
{'hi':3, 'hello': 6}
```

As I checked on the output, the words listed in the array a is still included in the dictionary. I hope you could help me, thank you!

Comment: so if the content of the row is 'and' you want to drop the row? without proper sample data is not easy to answer your question properly

Comment: hi @Yuca, I already edited my question. Feel free to inform me if there's still part of the question that you don't understand. Thank you!

Comment: ok, then what's happening is that you're asking if a word matches a list, not sure that's what you actually want to be checking against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [`df.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to replace the list `a` with `nan` and then [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to get a `dict()`:

```
#replace 0 with first col name
d=dict(df.replace(a,np.nan).dropna(subset=[0]).values)
```

---

```
{'hi': 3, 'hello': 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using pandas isin()

Assuming your dataframe looks like the one below, which I call `df` with columns "word" and "number".

```
    word    number
0   and     2
1   hi      3
2   or      4
3   is      5
4   hello   6
```

I would use the [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) function from pandas.

```
In [1]: a = ['and', 'or', 'is']
        df[~df['word'].isin(a)]
Out[1]: word    number
      1 hi      3
      4 hello   6
```

Then if you want a dictionary, you could just zip the columns you need.

```
In [2]: a = ['and', 'or', 'is']
        df2 = df[~df['word'].isin(a)]
        dict(zip(df2['word'], df2['number']))
Out[2]: {'hello': 6, 'hi': 3}
```

## Using your original code

If you want your original code to work, just replace the `if` and `break` statements.

```
d = {}
for k, v in df.values:
    print(k)
    if k in a:
        continue
    else:
        d[k] = int(v)
```

Note that `a` is a list and `k` is a string. So `a==k` will always evaluate to false and you never skip a value. Instead, you need to check whether `k in a`. Also, `break` is not really what you want as it would stop your for loop as soon as you encounter a value in `a`. What you need is `continue` so that you just move on to next value in your dataframe.